# How to retrieve a list of products with no price (empty field) in Customizable Options?

Tags: custom-options, empty

```
Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1
```

This could be due to us migrating from Magento 1.9.4 via the Magento Migration Tool. We keep getting phone calls from customers saying they are unable to add certain products to cart. Upon investigating this, I was able to find the root cause of this:

Most of the products have 3 custom options:

[image]

The problem appears when there is **nothing at all listed in the Price field** of the Regular size:

[image]

I have manually added in $0 for 2 products customers complained about yesterday and this fixed the issue and product can now be added to cart. This seems really odd that this even exists because when I try to remove the 0.00 afterwards and save the product, it adds in $0.00 automatically.

**How to identify which products in our database have nothing at all (empty field) for the price in custom options? Is there a script I could run in phpMyAdmin to identify those products?** *I wouldn't mind updating them manually if I can identify which products they are.*

I tried to Export all products and look through the spreadsheet but I don't think it will be possible to identify there?

Answer (score 0):

if custom module, identify the attribute and the table, after create a sql with (`select * from table where attribute = 0`) or something like that.

- first identify the attribute in the table